# Using a custom tikz library with defined colors for multiple figures

Tags: tikzlibrary

I am writing a document which includes several figures done in tikz and I want to use the same color in all of them. Currently, I am defining all of them in each file as `\definecolor{LightBlue}{HTML}{dae8fc}` for example. I would like to have a library with all the colors defined for all `.tikz` files.

I have a `tikzlibrarymycolors.code.tex` file with:

```
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{dae8fc}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{HTML}{6c8ebf}
\definecolor{darkGreen}{HTML}{82b366}
\definecolor{ligthGreen}{HTML}{d5e8d4}
```

And for each figure I include `\usetikzlibrary{mycolors}`. However, I get the error `Package tikz: I did not find the tikz library 'mycolors'. I looked for files named tikzlibrarymycolors.code.tex and pgflibrarymycolors.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees.`

I want to keep this library just locally to the current document. Do I need to build the texmf tree? I am using https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is your `tikzlibrarymycolors.code.tex` located? If it's in the same directory with your main tex file, compilation should work with no errors.

Comment: It is actually in a sub-directory. The main tex file is main.tex and the tikzlibrary with the .tikz files are in figures/

Comment: May I suggest you define the colors in the preamble ? So that you'll be allowed to call it everywhere in your document.

Comment: The issue with defining in the preamble is that I am also using tikzedt. That's why I'd rather have them in a separate file that I could also use with the editor

Answer (score 1):

By convention user-provided class, package, and package library files can, or should be either in the current working directory or in one of TDS (TeX Directory Structure) tress. See https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3 for a full list.

Using `\input` or `\usepackage` and the alike, one can specify a relative path like `\input{./sub/myfile.tex}`. But that won't win for `\tikzuselibrary` because you only gives it middle part of the file name, hence the control of file path prefixes is lost.

Fortunately, LaTeX provides an `\input@path` which can store a list of directories to search for input files. The last step is to make tikz/pgf aware of `\input@path`. See related pgf issue #565, [Use `\graphicspath` to search for images](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/565).

```
$ tree .
.
├── libs
│   └── tikzlibrarydemo.code.tex
└── main.tex

$ cat libs/tikzlibrarydemo.code.tex
% do sth so we know demo lib is successfully loaded
\tikzerror{lib demo}

\endinput
```

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists=\InputIfFileExists
% not necessary for current use case, but is actually more useful
% \let\pgfutil@IfFileExists=\IfFileExists

\def\input@path{{./libs/}}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{demo}

\begin{document}
content
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Do the color definitions and possibly other tikz-relevant codes have to be loaded in the form of a tikz library? Because there's almost no differences between `\tikzuselibrary{demo}` and `<optional \makeatletter>\input tikzlibrarydemo.code.tex<optional \makeatother>`.

Comment: Would it be easier/better to define all tikz-related in a "regular" .tex and include it in the preamble?

Comment: If relative path is involved, yes "regular" form is easier. Typically a pacakge/library is for some macros/settings that will be used by multiple main documents, and even different users.